# Given 2 numbers, build an array that holds all numbers within them

Tags: java

Refreshing my Java, With 2 numbers as user input , I'm trying to display all numbers in between. My code works using different types, likse strings, String builder and using Java8. But somehow, the Array part does not work..

Here is my code..

```
System.out.println("Enter the first number :");
            Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);

            int num1 = key.nextInt();
            int num2 =0;
            System.out.println("Enter the Second number :");
            try{
                  num2 = key.nextInt();
                do {
                    if (num2 < num1) {
                        System.out.println("Second number " + num2 + " is  less than " + num1);
                        System.out.println("Enter the Second number :");
                        num2 = key.nextInt();
                    }

                  } while(num2 <num1);
                }

            catch (ArithmeticException e) {

                if (num2 <num1)
                {
                    System.out.println("Second number " +num2 + "cannot be less than " + num1);

                }
            }

int length = (num2 - num1) +1;
            int [] numOfIntegers = new int [length];

            System.out.println("Now the length of numOfInteger is : " + numOfIntegers.length);

           // TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
            //int counter = num1;

            for(int i=num1;i<length; i++)
            {

                 numOfIntegers[i] = i ;
            }
```

RESULT is like this :
Numbers within 2 and 8 Using an Array is [0, 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

What am I doing wrong..

Answer (score 3):

**Java 8** allows to do that in one line with `IntStream` 
[DOCUMENTATION](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = IntStream.range(num1, num2+1).toArray();

        for(int aa:a)
        {
            System.out.println(aa);
        }
    }
```

> **EXAMPLE:** If you Substitute Num1= 2 and Num2=8 , Output Will be 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

Answer (score 2):

When you fill your array, you start at index `num1`. You should start at index `0`. That is

```
for(int i=num1;i<length; i++)
{
     numOfIntegers[i] = i ;
}
```

should be

```
for(int i=0; i < length; i++)
{
     numOfIntegers[i] = num1 + i;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add an variable to loop the array index from 0 th position to array length. Since your for loop first point to an index in the middle. i.e. here it is 2 and it goes forward up to array length. You could change it as below.

```
for ( int i = num1, k = 0; k < length; i++ )
{
    numOfInteger[k++] = i;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here in this loop:

```
for(int i=num1;i<length; i++)
{
      numOfIntegers[i] = i ;
}
```

You start adding at index `num1`, which is why the first couple slots in your `Array` are still your default value. You want to start the index at zero:

```
for(int i = num1, j = 0; j < length; i++) {
     numOfInteger[j++] = i;
}
```

Which will produce:

```
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

In the final loop:

```
for(int i = num1 ; i < length; i++)
{
numOfIntegers[i] = i ;
}
```

You are basically counting from num1 to length i.e the loop counter is being assigned values (2,3,4,5,6) and 0,1 positions of the array are being left out with 0 as default values.

Adjust the loop to iterate from 0 to length like below:

```
for(int i = 0 ;  i < length ; i++)
{
numOfIntegers[i] = num1 + i;
}
```